# custom msg throwing this error

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I´ve followed this tutorial about creating a custom msg: http://wiki.ros.org/msg, but instead of having strings as the content of my message file (`Num.msg`) i wanted my message to have this content:

```
std_msgs/Header header
```

...

```
uint8[] data
sensor_msgs/Image
```

But I´m getting this error when compiling it:

```
The dependencies of the message/service 'rqt_bag/Num' have changed. Please rerun cmake.
rqt_bag/CMakeFiles/_rqt_bag_generate_messages_check_deps_Num.dir/build.make:57:recipe for target 'rqt_bag/CMakeFiles/_rqt_bag_generate_messages_check_deps_Num'' failed
make[2]: * [rqt_bag/CMakeFiles/_rqt_bag_generate_messages_check_deps_Num] Error 1
CMakeFiles/MakeFiles2:858: recipe for target 'rqt_bag/CMakeFiles/_rqt_bag_generate_messages_check_deps_Num.dir/all' failed
make[1]: [rqt_bag/CMakeFiles/_rqt_bag_generate_messages_check_deps_Num.dir/all] Error 2 Makefile: 138: recipe for target 'all' failed make: ** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed
```

As i said before I´ve followed the tutorial, so i have modified the CMakeFile.txt and the package.xml as it is said in the tutorial adding those new fields. However if my message file have just "strings", for example, "string first_name", it all works.

Here is my `CMakeFile.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(rqt_bag)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
roscpp
rospy
std_msgs
message_generation
)

add_message_files(
FILES
Num.msg
)

generate_messages(
DEPENDENCIES
std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime
)

include_directories(
${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

install(FILES plugin.xml
DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)

install(DIRECTORY launch resource
DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)

install(PROGRAMS scripts/rqt_bag
DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

Why????? Thank you so much in advanced.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289984/custom-msg-throwing-this-error/) by [alejandro](https://answers.ros.org/users/34870/alejandro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-04-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robotchicken](https://answers.ros.org/users/34838/robotchicken/) on 2018-04-29**:
Can you paste your CMakeFile.txt?
I suspect the dependencty on std_msgs is probably not present.

**Comment by [robotchicken](https://answers.ros.org/users/34838/robotchicken/) on 2018-04-29**:
Forgot to mention earlier, can you try a `catkin_make clean` and then a `catkin_make`?

**Comment by [alejandro](https://answers.ros.org/users/34870/alejandro/) on 2018-04-29**:
Thats my CMakeFile.txt. What I actually want to do is to save in a bag file a message like sensor_msgs/Image apart from other parameters. So I´ve copied the content of sensor_msgs/Image into Num.msg to try to imitate the behaviour as I can´t modify the image.msg one.

**Comment by [alejandro](https://answers.ros.org/users/34870/alejandro/) on 2018-04-29**:
Sorry but I had forgotten one line in my Num.msg which is the last one: sensor_msgs/Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your custom message type includes sensor_msgs/image then you'll need to add a dependency on sensor_msgs as well as std_msgs for this to build successfully.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alejandro](https://answers.ros.org/users/34870/alejandro/) on 2018-04-29**:
Thats what I needed, thank u

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-29**:
@alejandro if this answered your question, then please mark it as correct by clicking on the check mark.